# Prevent deletion of all <li> tags in a content editable <ul>

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

When you backspace all the way to the beginning of a `<li>` tag within a content editable `<ul>` tag, all of the remaining `<li>` tags are deleted.

```
<ul contenteditable="true">
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q53V/

Put your cursor after the 'd' in world and backspace all the way to the beginning of the line. When you hit backspace again, it will also delete the 'Hello' list item. How can you prevent this behavior?

UPDATE: It looks like this behavior only exists in Chrome

Comment: Nope, it happens for me in firefox too.

Comment: PS: None of the solutions below for for me (Summer 2014).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have found:

> The erronous behavior of contenteditable lists in Opera and Chrome only occurs if the parent `ul` element is not followed by any other element with a minimum rendering space of 1px x 1px. The `display` value of the element doesn't matter, as long as it is non-empty or has a set height dimension with CSS.

So adding a simple `<div style="height: 1px;">` will answer your most direct question.

**However, You can't reliably use `contenteditable` lists in HTML at the time of asking.**

This question intrigued me and I tested it on *Moz FF 29-30, Opera 21, Google Chrome 35 & IE 11, on Win 8.1* . I tested simple keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

> **TL;DR**: IE 11 completely messes up, Opera & Chrome do pretty good if the `ul` is followed by an element with a rendered size, and Moz FF inserts a weird `<br type="_moz"></br>` tag. You would need `e.preventDefault()`, `e.keyCode/charCode` and the `Selection` & `Range` JS API to create a custom contenteditable list that works consistently across all browsers. However, these prerequisites already don't work consistently on all browsers. Best solution: use existing editors or some invisible text input for input.

These are the detailed gotcha's:

---

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a new `li` will add the following markup:

- *Opera and Google Chrome*: `<li><br><li>`
- *Moz FF*: `<li><br type="_moz"></br>`
- *IE 11*: if the active `li` is non-empty: `<li><br></li>`, if it is empty, IE completely messes up & inserts a `p`, then duplicates an empty `<ul contenteditable="">` after it, with only a `<br>` tag inside. This empty `ul` will be added **after** the element following the original element, if any.

---

Hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove a `li:not(:first-child)` will do the following:

- *Opera and Google Chrome*: if the `ul` is not followed by an element with a rendered size, all `li`'s will be deleted. If it is, the expected behavior occurs. (one `li` is removed).
- *Moz FF*: The expected behavior occurs (one `li` is removed). However, Moz FF moves the cursor out of the contenteditable area after removing a `li`.
- *IE 11*: Same behavior as when hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to remove the first `li` **should be prevented at all costs**.

For every browser tested, this breaks the list lay-out. All new <kbd>Enter</kbd> hits will generate `div`'s as direct children of the list.

---

Hitting <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove a subsequent `li` works consistently across all tested browsers. The subsequent `li` will be removed, and any content inside it will be transferred to the current `li`

---

Typing the first letter in an empty `li` will do the following:

- *Opera, IE11 and Google Chrome*: The letter is printed. The automatically inserted `<br>` tag is removed.
- *Moz FF*: The letter is printed. The custom `<br type="_moz">` tag is **not** removed.

Removing the only letter in an empty `li` will do the following:

- *Opera, IE11 and Google Chrome*: Another `<br>` tag is automatically inserted.
- *Moz FF*: Nothing. The custom `<br type="_moz">` is still present.

---

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q53V/8/ (first ul is with custom coded behavior, not perfect, second ul is standard)

Comment: The 1px height div fixed the bug for me. I was really stumped on this, and really appreciate your help and thorough response.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `contenteditable` on each of the `li` tag

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q53V/3/)

If you don't want to assign the attribute by yourself, you can use Javascript [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) which will take care of that - *(You've tagged Javascript in your question so I assume you are open to Javascript solution)*

```
var elm = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
for (var i=0; i < elm.length; i++) {
    elm[i].setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q53V/4/) *(Assigning attribute using Javascript)*

Just take a note over here, the selector am using in [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) is too general, will match ALL the `ul` elements in your document, so if you want to make a specific group of `li` elements editable, than assign a `class` or an `id` to your `ul` element and appropriately define a unique selector.

If you want multiple `ul` `li` editable, it would be better to define a `class` instead of an `id` as `id` has to be unique... So it would be cumbersome to define unique everytime you want a group of `li` to be editable.

Comment: That does prevent the deletion behavior I was seeing, but it also prevents deleting just one li, or hitting enter to add another li. What I'm looking for is behavior like you would find in a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @tilleryj WYSIWYG editors do delete the `li` if you press the backspace button.. :) if you want to append the li than use a button handler to append li on click of that button

Comment: I know they do, but they don't delete all of the li items, which is what happens with this example.

Comment: @tilleryj As I said, keep it like this and add a button to add `li` and delete the `li`

Comment: I want behavior that matches exactly what you would see in a wysiwyg editor, like if you add a bulleted list to a gmail message. Having a button for add/delete wouldn't work.

Comment: @tilleryj Sorry but I think you don't understand what am trying to explain, I cannot repeat myself, refer my first comment...

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Try out the jsfiddle that I linked. If you backspace to the beginning of the second li and hit backspace one more time, it should just delete the second li element, and place the cursor at the end of the first li element. That's not what happens though, it deletes both li elements.

Answer (score 0):

I had also same problem . So, I solved it by doing preventdefault() for backspace .Here I am getting all the Uls using querySelectorAll. For each ul I am checking the childrenLength i.e li tags and textContent.
I am also checking for textcontent because otherwise user won't be able to delete any li when it is empty.

Based on this I am Disabling the Backspace.
In this code I have done this for Muliple Uls

```js
const allULList = document.querySelectorAll(".TaskList");
allULList.forEach((list) => {
  list.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    const childrenLength = list.children.length;
    const emptytext = list.textContent.trim().length;
    if (emptytext === 0 && e.key === "Backspace" && childrenLength === 1) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```